# Movie clip doesn't get instantiated

Tags: actionscript

I am using Adobe Flash Pro CC, AS3 & scaleform.

I create an instance of an object which contains AS Linkage and a use class definition.
Regardless I can visually identify the object is loaded, the constructor class of this object never gets called.
I tried re-creating the object in the scene, renaming, etc... but it still produces the same error.
When running the GfxMediaPlayer, I can see an 1009 error is displayed; a common mistake when the AS Linkage is missing.

Is there any other option for this kind of objects that is restricting how it gets instantiated?

My scene contains several objects that use similar layout and scaleform.clik libraries, but they work as expected an they do get instantiated.

I also have tested this on Flash CS6 with same results, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the library path for the object was missing. The strange thing, is that same path was used by the rest of the objects that were working fine, no idea how they would be working.